# How to navigate back in browser's history in Geb test

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, geb

Inside a Geb test, I'd like to navigate back in the browser's history (ie. to click the browser's back button). I haven't found a way to do it using Geb API.

What I do is:

```
driver.navigate().back()               // usage of WebDriver API
browser.page(<<previous Page class>>)  // this tells Geb that the page has changed
```

The code works, but I don't like the usage of WebDriver API here. Another idea would be to do it in JavaScript, but that's also something I'd like to avoid.

Is there a more Gebish way of navigating back in the browser's history?

Comment: `driver.navigate().back()` seems like exactly the right mechanism. Instead of doing the normal thing, interacting with a `Page` and clicking links, you're invoking an actual browser feature. As such, you're having to interact with `driver` directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe there isn't. I would also use WebDriver API to navigate back. Sometimes it's necessary to use WebDriver API, that's why the WebDriver instance is exposed on Geb's Browser class.